# xdef and cedille

Tags: tex-core, expansion

I need to xdef some data. In rare cases it'll contain cedilles like:

```
\xdef\xxx{spam\c{e}eggs}
\bye
```

Unfortunately this failes. Is there a chance to get this working?

(I'm on LaTeX in my code, using etoolbox, but to my understanding the above plain tex example is identical. And minimal.)

Comment: Use `\makeatletter \protected@xdef\x{spam\c{e}eggs} \makeatother` ...

Comment: in latex you should never use `\xdef` on general text use `\protected@xdef` and the `\c` will be kept safe.

Comment: It is good to chose a minimal example but here your example is actually a rather different case. the definitions of `\c` in plain tex and latex are completely different. `\c` in plain is a simple macro that always places a cedilla under its argument using an align construct. in latex it is a font encoding specific command that may use an alignment or a pre-built glyph from the font for encodings that include such characters.

Answer (score 6):

In plain TeX you could use

```
\xdef\xxx{spam\noexpand\c{e}eggs}
\bye
```

In LaTex you could also do that but far better would be to use

```
\protected@xdef\xxx{spam\c{e}eggs}
```

assuming `@` is a letter at that point (in a package file).

Note, the definitions of `\c` in plain tex and latex are completely different. `\c` in plain is a simple macro that always places a cedilla under its argument using an align construct. in latex it is a font encoding specific command that may use an alignment or a pre-built glyph from the font for encodings that include such characters.

Comment: This was very helpful. While I'm using etoolbox on LaTeX in the end, I needed to add `protect@` to `csxdef` and `eappto` and got it working. Great, thanks a lot!